# How to find the number of deliveries each agent has to make

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists, one contains data of subscribers and another one has the data of agents. I need to find how many clients does each agent has in the month that is requested (it is entered by keyboard).

Agent list goes as follows: Agent Code, Lastname, Firstname.

Subscriber list goes as follows: Subscribers Lastname, agent code, starting month of subscription, length of subscription.

I tried using this method, but it returns not the number of deliveries each agent has to make, but it sums up the lengths of subscriptions.

```
void WorkLoad(List<Subscriber> A, List<Agent> B)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var sub = A.ToArray();
            var agent = B.ToArray();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sub.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (sub[j].StartingMonth <= i &&
                        sub[j].StartingMonth + sub[j].Length >= i)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < agent.Length; k++)
                        {
                            if (agent[j].AgentCode == sub[k].AgentsCode)
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The culprit should be at `agent[j].AgentCode == sub[k].AgentsCode`: you swapped the indexer variables `j` and `k`. Suggestion: you should avoid magic numbers (like 12) and should name your indexers (and variables in general) with more meaningful keywords: that would have avoided the mistake.

Comment: Well, I tried your solution but now it gives System.OutOfMemory exception and I'm starting to think that my approach to the problem is wrong, but I have no idea how could I solve it differently

Comment: And it is because of  var sub=A.ToArray();  it returns null